# How to empty User Profile Database after applying filter?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

The current UPA shows 7000 users (including bunch of service accounts). I just added 4 exclusion filters so that number of users is back to 2000. I did a full sync but all the service accounts and junk accounts are still there and number is 7,000. Is there a way to empty the UPA DB without re-creating the entire UPA. It's a new SharePoint 2013 environment. Also user and group was selected under "configure sync settings" but i changed that to Users Only.

I am using UPSS Import.

Comment: Are you using AD Import or UPSS?

Comment: This site is not letting me add comment. Is there any update to my question? I have tons of junks in the UPA now (groups, service accounts, etc.). What's the best way to clean this up?